# Lodash return object of array that have true value in object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have an array of objects, Like for example if I have 4 objects in the array. I just want to return those object which has `status: true`. Could someone please help me with how to resolve this issue?
thanks

```
  const inputArray = [
    {id: 1, status: true},
    {id: 2, status: true},
    {id: 3, status: false},
    {id: 4, status: true},
    {id: 5, status: true},
    {id: 6, status: false}
];





 const countDeliveredDeliveries = (array) => {
    let result = array.map(function (item) {
      return item.status === "Delievered";
    });

    console.log("@@ reesult", result);
  };
```

Comment: so, you want to filter an array of objects,

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: https://lodash.com/docs/#countBy

Comment: In your case, simply replacing .map with .filter should suffice.